# Icons on the mobile site's inbox lack detail

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web, retina

On the mobile website, the icons representing each site in the inbox are a bit unpolished. It's especially noticeable on the iPhone 4's retina display.  I also noticed that the Meta Stack Overflow icon seems cut off to fit the dimensions of the icon. It seems as if the mobile site is taking the icons from somewhere else, downscaling it, and using it on this part of the site (which would explain the MSO icon getting cut off and the pixel artifacts).

Perhaps it could instead use the icons used in the full site's inbox?

[image]

Comment: And to compensate for the lack of detail in the icons, I've posted the largest and most detailed screenshot I could get from my giant iPhone.

Comment: We'll get this network looking great on our iPhones yet!

Comment: On an older iPhone, the inbox unread count is a clunky box. Stupid moz-rounded.

Answer (score 1):

We are using retina-friendly icons now.

Answer (score -2):

Remember, the mobile site's supposed to be *minimal*. Possession of a shiny new phone with a ridiculously{*} hi-res display has no corellation with your data plan/speed. Thus, the SE team tries to reduce load on the mobile site wherever possible (I know this from the responses I've seen [on all the other mobile site "bugs"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile+status-bydesign)).

That being said, I do see that it's not a *big* difference in load. It seems like [the gods are already working on this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131045/optimise-stack-exchange-user-flair-for-retina-displays#comment360851_131045), though not with regard to the mobile site.

Devs: [This](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2012/04/javascript-package-offers-a-smarter-way-to-serve-hi-res-images.ars) shiny new library may be useful, though it may add to load on the mobile site.

<sup>*Yes, you guessed it, I'm jealous ;-)</sup>