# Optimise Stack Exchange user flair for Retina displays

Tags: feature-request, design, flair, retina

I really love the way [user flair](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/flair/info) works, but unfortunately it doesn't look very sharp on a [Retina display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_display), especially when juxtaposed with browser-rendered text. If you made the generated image twice its current size, it would circumvent this problem.

Could you please generate larger source images? Keeping the same width and height HTML attributes will mean that the image won't look any different for current users, so there's no chance of anything breaking.

It's a small difference, but quality is in the details!

Comment: We're aware and taking a look at all things with relation to retina, not a trivial thing to do across all sites (and with APIs, not breaking apps that depend on a certain long-established resolution, etc)...but we're working on it.

Comment: @Nick not _exactly_ useful here, but useful to your general resolution goal: http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2012/04/javascript-package-offers-a-smarter-way-to-serve-hi-res-images.ars

Comment: @Manishearth I don't see how that's better than the CSS min-device-pixel-ratio media query.

Comment: @Jezen that will work in this case, but it may be a usefull tool overall--I dunno.

Comment: Related: [SVG Flairs (In Addition To PNG Flairs)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65759/svg-flairs-in-addition-to-png-flairs)

Comment: @Nick **four years later**, any updates? You can say "we worked on it, it's not possible", but please, just saying "we're working on it" never to come back is just... well.

Comment: JSON now doesn't supply the gravatar info any more https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1.json so grumpydev fails grumpydev.com/2009/07/11/stack-overflow-share-your-flair-now-in-png/, stackimage stopped somewhere in 2012 http://web.archive.org/web/20120705062707/http://stackimage.quickmediasolutions.com/ and the stackexchange multi-site flair doesn't deliver html (only PNG, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278394/flair-no-html-version-on-stackexchange?noredirect=1#comment901742_278394 ) so there is some work overdue (:

Comment: **7 years later**, any updates?

Comment: Corresponding request on MSO: [Flair images low resolution on retina displays](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262704/1478931)