# When will Stack Overflow support retina devices?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, retina

When will Stack Overflow support retina devices?

Please, please, please at least change the favicon to a high-res version.

[image: What´s wrong?]

Comment: I realise I said this last time (will try to find duplicate) but isn't it impossible to support retina displays absolutely because the actual pixel density is completely dependant on viewing distance (or in other words super vague)

Comment: @RichardTingle: What do you mean? Retina displays only have a higher DPI, and so upscaled fonts...what does viewing distance have to do with it?

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby "Retina Display, stylized as Retina display, is a brand name used by Apple for liquid crystal displays that have a pixel density high enough that the human eye is unable to discern individual pixels at a typical viewing distance. [....] Because the typical viewing distance is different, depending on each device's use, the pixels per inch claimed to be of Retina quality can differ"

Comment: You are a little angry at the logo there.

Comment: @RichardTingle: Oh, I was simply thinking of high DPI devices (so a bigger favicon or a vector version would be needed).

Comment: @RichardTingle if other sites do it, it proves that it's not impossible. The icons of those other sites he got there are perfect while Stack Overflow favicon is not.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not against upping the resolution, which will obviously help. I have just developed an irrational hatred to the term "retina display" and would rather people used less vague terms (or terms which are not actually brand names).

Comment: @RichardTingle fair enough. Anyway, found one official response, in a comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131045/optimise-stack-exchange-user-flair-for-retina-displays?rq=1#comment360851_131045

Comment: Images would need to be 3x bigger to support current devices with the highest pixel densities (devicePixelRatio == 3). Can simulate it by zooming browser to 200% or 300%. Yeah, trade names for simple things like high-res displays are obnoxious.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Fully agreed that it's not impossible, and even that it would be nice. But that's the extent of it. Considering that there a million things that are possible for the team to work on, it becomes an issue of priority.

Comment: @AaronBertrand well, one has to dress nicely if he want to get the most respect from other people. As it stands, Stack Overflow isn't dressed as nicely as it can. Personally I don't really care but there are many who do care.

Comment: @ShadowWizard you could also argue that if people judge you solely by what you are wearing (or, more analogous, solely by the color of the toe of your socks), you should care far less about their opinion.

Comment: @AaronBertrand not solely. I think there's a discussion about it somewhere, will try to find it.