# @1x Image resolution on answers/questions

Tags: bug, design

I am using chrome on a Mac Retina Display, the avatar image under the answers/questions is using a 32x32 image resolution, which makes the image looks ugly on retina display screens.

[image]

Using @2x image size (64x64) and rescaling, will look much better
[image]

I don't see the problem anywhere else on the website (all the other avatars I have in different places use 2x the size and rescale.

I am using gravatar for my profile image/avatar

**Note**:

These questions reference the same topic:

- [Optimise Stack Exchange user flair for Retina displays](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131045)
- [HDPI version of Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161373)

But the retina display is implemented (these posts are many years old), this is a bug in the implementation (that they missed this one).

Comment: See also: [Optimise Stack Exchange user flair for Retina displays](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131045/21960)

Comment: See also: [HDPI version of Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161373/21960)

Comment: @ale correct, these reference the same topic, but the ratina display is implemented (these posts are many years old), this is a bug in the implementation (that they missed this one)

Comment: I didn't see this question, and asked my own a while back. (: There is a slight difference, though, in that I'm using SE-hosted images instead of Gravatar. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316832/avatars-in-answer-boxes-are-downscaled-incorrectly-on-retina-displays